# Outlook 2010 only a few IMAP-Folders showing

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, imap

A customer of mine has a strange problem. In Outlook 2010 (Home and Business) there are only a few IMAP folders showing up.

I tried `Right click on Account > Update Folder List` and `Right click on Account > IMAP folders > Query`

But only a few (5 out of ca. 50) are showing up.

[Folders not showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eofAe.png)

---

On my virtual machine with Outlook 2010 (Professional Plus) and the same email account with the same settings. Everything works fine.

[Folders showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvpPM.png)

---

In both cases Outlook runs on Windows 7 Professional SP1

Does anyone know, what additional steps i could take to further troubleshoot the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was because of Kaspersky Internet Security 2016.
I think it's a bug.

## Solution 1

- Turn off Anti-Spam

## Solution 2

- Go to advanced settings of mail anti-virus > connectivity
- Disable scan POP3, SMTP, NNTP, and IMAP traffic

After turning off these settings Outlook worked correctly. Keep in mind that these two solutions may lessen the effectiveness of Kaspersky.